# javascript function for moving elements is accessing more elements than it should.

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I would like the lightblue square to go right, and the orange one to go down at the same time. But they both go diagonally. I understand kinda whats happening here, but I don't see why it is happening or how to fix it. It looks like both function calls are effecting both elements. Thanks!

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8apLsmp7/1/

```
        function moveElem(dir, xPos, yPos, element, index, container){

            //Getting width and height of container and item elements
            var elem = document.getElementsByClassName(element);
            var w = elem[index].offsetWidth;
            var h = elem[index].offsetHeight;
            var contw = document.getElementById(container).offsetWidth;
            var conth = document.getElementById(container).offsetHeight;
            var vertEnd = contw - w;
            var horiEnd = conth - h;

            //clean up variables to make sure they comply with the width and height of the container
            if (xPos > vertEnd){
                x = vertEnd;
            } else if (xPos < 0){
                x = 0;
            } else {
                x = xPos;
            }               

            if (yPos > horiEnd){
                y = horiEnd;
            } else if (yPos < 0){
                y = 0;
            } else {
                y = yPos;
            }

            //position the element
            elem[index].style.left = x + 'px';
            elem[index].style.top = y + 'px';


            //set timer, speed and friction
            var timer = setInterval(frame, 5);
            var spd = 10;
            var friction = 0.987;

            //what runs every interval
            function frame(){
                //check if to move right
                if (dir === "right"){
                    if (x >= vertEnd){
                        clearInterval(timer);
                        x = vertEnd;
                        elem[index].style.left = x + 'px';
                        elem[index].style.top = y + 'px';

                    } else {
                        elem[index].style.top = y + 'px';
                        elem[index].style.left = x + 'px';
                        x += spd;
                        spd *= friction;

                    }
                //check if to move left
                } else if (dir === "left"){
                    if (x <= 0){
                        clearInterval(timer);
                        x = 0;
                        elem[index].style.left = x + 'px';
                        elem[index].style.top = y + 'px';

                    } else {
                        elem[index].style.top = y + 'px';
                        elem[index].style.left = x + 'px';
                        x -= spd;
                        spd *= friction;

                    }
                //check if to move up
                } else if (dir === "up"){
                    if (y <= 0){
                        clearInterval(timer);
                        y = 0;
                        elem[index].style.left = x + 'px';
                        elem[index].style.top = y + 'px';

                    } else {
                        elem[index].style.left = x + 'px';
                        elem[index].style.top = y + 'px';
                        y -= spd;
                        spd *= friction;

                    }
                //check if to move down
                }  else if (dir === "down"){
                    if (y >= horiEnd){
                        clearInterval(timer);
                        y = horiEnd;
                        elem[index].style.left = x + 'px';
                        elem[index].style.top = y + 'px';

                    } else {
                        elem[index].style.left = x + 'px';
                        elem[index].style.top = y + 'px';
                        y += spd;
                        spd *= friction;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        moveElem("right", 0, 0, "item", 0, "cont");
        moveElem("down", 0, 0, "item", 1, "cont");
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping/debugging/logging to see where things go wrong? https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask because you aren't going to get many good answers to "debug my code for me".

Comment: Thanks! ill try those!

Answer (score 0):

You might have some errors in your original code. Try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ut61pnsa/). (untidy version - you can clean it up later)

```
<body>
  <div id="cont">
    <div id="item1" class="item"></div>
    <div id="item2" class="item"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

```
//what runs every interval
function frame(obj) {
  const {
    dir,
    spd,
    friction,
    elem,
    vertEnd,
    horiEnd,
    x,
    y
  } = obj;
  //check if to move right
  if (dir === "right") {
    if (x >= vertEnd) {
      //clearInterval(timer);
      obj.x = vertEnd;
      elem.style.left = x + 'px';
      elem.style.top = y + 'px';

    } else {
      elem.style.top = y + 'px';
      elem.style.left = x + 'px';
      obj.x += spd;
      obj.spd *= friction;

    }
    //check if to move left
  } else if (dir === "left") {
    if (x <= 0) {
      //clearInterval(timer);
      obj.x = 0;
      elem.style.left = x + 'px';
      elem.style.top = y + 'px';

    } else {
      elem.style.top = y + 'px';
      elem.style.left = x + 'px';
      obj.x -= spd;
      obj.spd *= friction;

    }
    //check if to move up
  } else if (dir === "up") {
    if (y <= 0) {
      //clearInterval(timer);
      obj.y = 0;
      elem.style.left = x + 'px';
      elem.style.top = y + 'px';

    } else {
      elem.style.left = x + 'px';
      elem.style.top = y + 'px';
      obj.y -= spd;
      obj.spd *= friction;

    }
    //check if to move down
  } else if (dir === "down") {
    if (y >= horiEnd) {
      //clearInterval(timer);
      obj.y = horiEnd;
      elem.style.left = x + 'px';
      elem.style.top = y + 'px';

    } else {
      elem.style.left = x + 'px';
      elem.style.top = y + 'px';
      obj.y += spd;
      obj.spd *= friction;

    }
  }
}

function moveElem(dir, xPos, yPos, element, index, container) {

  //Getting width and height of container and item elements
  var elem = document.getElementById(element);
  var w = elem.offsetWidth;
  var h = elem.offsetHeight;
  var contw = document.getElementById(container).offsetWidth;
  var conth = document.getElementById(container).offsetHeight;
  var vertEnd = contw - w;
  var horiEnd = conth - h;

  //clean up variables to make sure they comply with the width and height of the container
  if (xPos > vertEnd) {
    x = vertEnd;
  } else if (xPos < 0) {
    x = 0;
  } else {
    x = xPos;
  }

  if (yPos > horiEnd) {
    y = horiEnd;
  } else if (yPos < 0) {
    y = 0;
  } else {
    y = yPos;
  }

  //position the element
  elem.style.left = x + 'px';
  elem.style.top = y + 'px';


  //set timer, speed and friction
  var spd = 10;
  var friction = 0.987;
  var obj = {
    dir,
    spd,
    friction,
    elem,
    vertEnd,
    horiEnd,
    x,
    y
  };
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    frame(obj)
  }, 5);

}
moveElem("right", 0, 0, "item1", 0, "cont");
moveElem("down", 0, 0, "item2", 1, "cont")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Need to improve in frame function. Pass argument as suggested by Roby Rodriguez or as given below link:
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ashishmittalam92/jkccaha9/ is working fine. Try this.